# Same Perl script running fine in DEV and Failing in QA

Tags: perl

I have a perl script which reads a file and writes the content of the file read into another file. The strange thing is that the code is executing fine in the DEV environment but its failing with the error 
Use of uninitialized value $ofh in print at /ms/dist/msamg/PROJ/agcis/qa/perl/acd_pas_model_accounts.pl line 183,  line 4

Please advise.

Below is the snippet of the perl code :

```
    my @filetomail = ("$opt->{RptDir}pas_acct_model_rtp.csv");
    my $ofh = new IO::File "$opt->{RptDir}/pas_acct_model_rtp.csv", "w";
    print $ofh;
    unless (defined $ofh) {
    $log->log (MSLogErr, "Error open file");
    program_exit(6);
    }
```

Comment: Very likely rights/config in QA environment (not shown in your snippet). What populates `$opt->{RptDir}`? In addition your `@filetomail` variable has a different path than you open - which means if you have an old version of the file hanging around from previous tests, it may work in your tests, but actually be a bug (thus QA doing its job correctly!)

Comment: It doesn't make sense to `print $ofh` if you haven't yet verified that it is defined as you do on the following line.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem isn't with IO::File, it's with the building of the file name.  It's always a good idea to build the file name string and assign it to a variable before using it to open a file.  That way, you can print it to verify that it's what you expect, and by using the variable, you avoid building the string multiple times, and can be certain that what you're printing is the same as what you're using to open the file.  It also keeps your code cleaner.  Consider these two options:

```
my $ofh = new IO::File "$opt->{RptDir}/pas_acct_model_rtp.csv", "w";
```

and

```
my $file_name = "$opt->{RptDir}/pas_acct_model_rtp.csv";
print "File name: '$file_name'\n";
my $ofh = IO::File->new($file-name, "w");
```

PBP suggests bounding the variable's interpolated value with single quotes in order to further insurer that you're seeing the true value of the string.  This approach will hilight things like preceding or trailing spaces.

You may also need to inspect $opt.  Data::Dumper is your friend.  A good friend.